# Set Boinc as a screensaver

Tags: screensaver

I have a [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) Manager installed contributing to [World Community Grid](http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org/).

Is there a way to set this to run as a screensaver visually in Ubuntu?

Comment: They don't have an screensaver for linux like the one on windows, with the animation of processing if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not an option for the Ubuntu/Linux version.

(NB: It has been suggested that running the screensaver uses CPU power that could be used to contribute even more data!)

Comment: I don't understand why they would break away from the Windows and Mac visual screensavers.  I'd just like to have the same behavior.

Comment: I think the decision has to do with the number of window managers we have on Linux : KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc...
I'm not sure a single screen saver could work on all of them. They would need to make multiple ones, or select just one or two they would support (making the rest of the community unhappy)... Not easy, and lot of work, for a feature that is a comodity rather than the main focus.
With MAC and Windows, the work is easier (only one format for each platform).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is built in Boinc, but hasn't sucessfully been ported to the various distro's screensavers

http://www.spy-hill.com/~myers/help/boinc/unix-screensaver.html

http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=7139

Would be nice if this was enabled

Comment: here is the code - via the boinc.berkeley forum -http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/browser/boinc/branches/boinc_core_release_6_12/clientscr/screensaver_x11.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do know that, but just to be sure: You are not trying to make BOINC work during the times that you don't use the computer yourself, or are you? Because you can configure that behaviour in the BOINC manager, even without it being the active screen saver.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can have BOINC run.  I'm specifically looking to have it run as a screensaver visually, just like how it runs on Windows/Mac.